# Backwards-compatible migration of Spring Boot REST API to Protobuf, while still supporting JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am new to Protocol Buffers.

I have a Spring Boot REST API with different stakeholders. Some API users need to be able to use the API in JSON format (ease of use, external tooling support, etc.), some other users are asking for Protobufs to be able to generate client code. The API also needs to remain properly documented. Right now, we are using OpenAPI 3.0 format.

This is how one of our example DTOs look like:

```
@Builder
@With
public record ExampleDTO(

  @Schema(hidden = true)
  @Deprecated
  String field1,

  @Schema(description = "Field 2", example = "Required example value")
  @NotBlank
  String field2

}
```

Our DTOs are currently highly Java-annotation driven (documentation, Bean Validation constraints, etc.)

From what I understand is with Protobufs, we would migrate those DTOs to a `.proto` definition. For example:

```
message ExampleDTO {
  optional string field1 = 1;
  required string field2 = 2;
}
```

**Open questions**

1. Can users still opt into JSON serialization format (e.g. via `Content-Type` HTTP header), in a way so that we do not break existing functionality?
2. Is my understanding correct that we would no longer be able to use Bean Validation (https://beanvalidation.org/2.0-jsr380/) with protobuf-generated DTOs? What can we migrate to that hooks into our documentation generation (e.g. `@NotBlank`, `@Min`, `@Max`, ...)?
3. What tools are available to generate documentation UIs? Do we have have to ditch swagger and if so, what to use instead?

Comment: Protos are a serialization format, not an RPC system.  (That would likely be gRPC.)  You are unlikely to be able to use any annotation-based validation or documentation with protos.

Comment: That's correct. I am only looking for switching to a new serialization format, to use Protobufs for my REST endpoints, not change them over to an RPC-style API. I understand that I'm entering opinion territory here - but what would be an idiomatic way to approach validation and API documentation, with Java?